# Packet saving with time stamp in JS

Tags: node.js

I am new to Nodejs and JS, I am writing a Server using NodeJS which gets packet from a remote device every minute. I want to save each packet in a file with arrival time and date of the packet and new file should be made each day.
Thnxxxx in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you need ? Solution, design or code ?

Comment: Well I need a code doing similar kinda job just to have knowledge of how its being done, not necessarily doing the same thing, But similar kinda operations like saving with arrival time and date, and new file each day.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some logging scheme to keep track of data and time and you can also configure it to create new log file every day. Should leverage something from these repositories - https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node and https://github.com/winstonjs/winston